# About the least common multiple of numbers and combinatorial

Tags: divisibility, combinations

Prove that for any positive integer $n$, the least common multiple of the
numbers $1, 2, 3, \ldots , n$ and the least common multiple of the numbers: ${n\choose 1}, {n\choose 2}, \ldots , {n\choose n}$
are equal if and only if $n + 1$ is a prime number.

**My quest**

$$X_n=\{1, 2, 3, \ldots , n\}, Y_n=\left\{{n\choose 1}, {n\choose 2}, \ldots , {n\choose n}\right\}.$$

After some calculus, I'm pretty sure about this assumption: $p$ prime divides one of the $X_n$ elements if and only if $p$ divides one of the $Y_n$ elements happens if and only if $n+1$ is prime. This, I think, will solve half of the problem. Anyway, I'm unable to prove or disprove the assumption. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The central binomial coefficient is a multiple of every prime in the range $\left(\frac{n}{2},n\right)$, disregarding the primality of $n+1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Right, but this fact doesn't seem to disprove my assumption

Comment: But proves that, assuming that $n+1$ is not a prime and your conjecture holds, the exceptional prime that does not divide any of the $\binom{n}{i}$ has to be small. So, it may be worthy to look for the maximum power of two in the two lcms.

Comment: I think that we can prove that for every $p$ we have :$$v_p(\text{lcm}(X_{n+1}))=(n+1)v_p(\text{lcm}(Y_n)) $$ I have seen this in a paper , I will look for it

Comment: @Elaqqad Could you tell me what $v_p$ is?

Comment: $v_p(n)$ is the largest integer $k$ such that $p^k$ divides $n$, and I found the article if you're interested (There must be a simple proof for this case) because the paper discuss a more general identity and uses Lucas's theorem : [An identity involving the least common multiple of binomial coefficients and its application](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2295)

Comment: @Elaqqad It proves that $\text{lcm}(X_{n+1})=(n+1)\text{lcm}(Y_n)$ and this solves my problem. But the demonstration is quite complicate. Thank you, it's a huge step forward for me.

Comment: Yes that's correct, but maybe there will be a simpler way of solving your problem without using the result in the paper because its more general.

Comment: @Elaqqad Right, I'll keep this question open

Comment: See [OEIS A$002944$](http://oeis.org/A002944).

Comment: @Lucian I only need a quite elementary solution